# group by 15-minute interval in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

here's a sample from my table in Metabase PostgreSQL:

```
timestamp
2023-01-25T05:00:01+03:00
2023-01-25T05:01:01+03:00
2023-01-25T05:05:01+03:00
2023-01-25T05:13:01+03:00
2023-01-25T05:14:01+03:00
2023-01-25T05:20:01+03:00
2023-01-25T05:24:01+03:00
2023-01-25T05:29:01+03:00
```

I want to group by 15-minute interval and count events that happen in the interval:

```
timestamp            count
2023-01-25T05:00     5
2023-01-25T05:15     3
```

this didn't work

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', timestamp_column) + (floor(date_part('minute', timestamp_column) / 15) * interval '15 minute') AS interval_start,
       COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY interval_start
```

and raised an error:

```
   Code: 46. DB::Exception: Unknown function date_part: While processing dateTrunc('hour', timestamp) + (floor(date_part('minute', timestamp) / 15) * toIntervalMinute(15)) AS interval_start. 
(UNKNOWN_FUNCTION) (version 22.12.1.1752 (official build)) , server ClickHouseNode [uri=http://clickhouse:8123/table_group, options={socket_timeout=300000,use_server_time_zone_for_dates=true}]@-196298079
```

Comment: That's not a Postgres error message. Please tag your question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run your code and it is working [fine](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e13BD2bKiHi3TC6Z6ByjYd/0):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    timestamp_column TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO my_table (timestamp_column)
VALUES 
    ('2023-01-25T05:00:01+03:00'),
    ('2023-01-25T05:01:01+03:00'),
    ('2023-01-25T05:05:01+03:00'),
    ('2023-01-25T05:13:01+03:00'),
    ('2023-01-25T05:14:01+03:00'),
    ('2023-01-25T05:20:01+03:00'),
    ('2023-01-25T05:24:01+03:00'),
    ('2023-01-25T05:29:01+03:00');

SELECT date_trunc('hour', timestamp_column) + (floor(date_part('minute', timestamp_column) / 15) * interval '15 minute') AS interval_start,
       COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY interval_start
```

[image]

In your error message we got info about `ClickHouseNode`. For ClickHOuse you can use [toStartOfInterval](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/#tostartofintervaltime_or_data-interval-x-unit--time_zone) instead as the date_part funcion is not avaible there. From the docs it seems to be something like:

```
toStartOfInterval(t, INTERVAL 15 minute)
```

but I am not able to test it.

Comment: yes! `toStartOfInterval(t, INTERVAL 15 minute)` solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL version 14+ adds [date_bin()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) function. You can directly use date_bin() to extract the inforamtion you need.

Here is the [query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oh89fEdZaHYMh6mGCG6dtQ/1):

```
SELECT
   DATE_BIN('15 minutes', timestamp_column, TIMESTAMP '2001-01-01') AS interval_start,
   COUNT(1)
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
   interval_start
```

| interval_start | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-25T02:00:00.000Z | 5 |
| 2023-01-25T02:15:00.000Z | 3 |